# Android Studio: New activity opens as blank screen

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-studio

Hello!
I'm just starting in Android Studio. I searched for a matching question but no joy, please yell out if you've seen this one already!

My main activity has a single button which opens the second activity, the button works and it opens. But the second activity shows as a blank screen instead of the text that should be there.

Apologies for any irrelevant copy/paste!

Manifest:

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".fiveThreeOne"
            android:label="@string/title531">
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Main activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:textColor="#ffdedede"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="fiveThreeOne"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:id="@+id/open531btn"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainTitle"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Button code in main class

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button open531button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.open531btn);
        open531button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v){
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, fiveThreeOne.class));
            }
        });

    }
```

Second activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/title531"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:editable="false"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:id="@+id/title531"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you set the layout for your activity in the line setContentView() like this. Here activity_second is the activity layout of my SecondActivity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    }
```

if not then your activity will show up as blank.
Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Spot on! I dropped your block in right under the public class headline (with the class name adjusted) and it worked right away - thanks!

Comment: In my case I've implemented `override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {` what causes issue

Comment: May be you overrided `public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState)`  instead of `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

Answer (score 96):

It sometimes happens when instead of overloading

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

you end up overloading

```
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState)
```

instead.
Make sure the onCreate with only savedInstanceState as a argument is overloaded.

Comment: you've probably meant overriding

Comment: Ah this answer saved my day after wasting hours figuring out why my compose screen was blank. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check weather you have set the correct layout for the setContentView() method of your second activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can just go to dependencies in build.gradle file and add this line there.. & try.

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I changed device in Android Virtual Divice Manager and this fix problem